# Set navigator parameters from child navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a Stack navigator (`RecipesTab`) nested in a Tab navigator (`NavBar`) and I'm trying to hide the Tab Bar on `RecipeSite`. My current solution is to pass `showTabBar` up the tree but I'm having trouble setting the navigation parameters for `NavBar` from `RecipesTab`. Wondering if it's possible to somehow call `this.props.navigation.setParams({...})` from the `RecipesTab` navigator or pass parameters to `NavBar` from `RecipesTab` in another way.

```
//class RecipeList...
//class IngredientsTab...

class RecipeSite extends Component {
    render() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({showTabBar: false});
        return;
    }
}

const RecipesTab = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Main: {
            screen: RecipeList,
        },
        Site: {
            screen: RecipeSite,
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Main',
    }
);

export default NavBar = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Recipe: {
        screen: RecipesTab,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          tabBarVisible: navigation.getParam('showTabBar', true)
        }),
      },
      Ingredient: {
        screen: IngredientsTab,
      }
    },
  );`
```

Basically I'm just trying to send data from `RecipesTab` to `NavBar`.